# How to update a child when it's parent changes value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show progress of download on my UI. I have made a ListView.builder, in which I am passing list of current downloads. I have made a child widget, which displays `LinearProgressIndicator` for the same. Here are my code snippets:

```
  loadCurrentDownloads() async {
    var temp = await FlutterDownloader.loadTasks()??[];
    setState(() {
      downloadTasks = temp;
    });
    downloadProgresses=List.filled(downloadTasks.length, ValueNotifier(0.0));
  }

ListView.builder(
                itemCount: downloadTasks.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  downloadProgresses[index].value = downloadTasks[index].progress*0.01;
                    if(downloadTasks[index].status==DownloadTaskStatus.running) {
                      return ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: downloadProgresses[index],
                        builder: (context, progress, child) {
                          return DownloadsFilesTile(
                            fileName: downloadTasks[index].filename??'',
                            path: downloadTasks[index].savedDir,
                            progress: progress, //downloadTasks[index].progress*0.01,
                            taskId: downloadTasks[index].taskId,
                            cancelFunction: (val) {
                              if(val==true) {
                                setState(() {
                                  downloadTasks.removeAt(index);
                                });
                              }
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }
                    else {
                      return const SizedBox();
                    }
                },
              ),
```

And inside my `DownloadsFilesTile` widget, I am using LinearProgressIndicator like this:

```
return LinearProgressIndicator(
        value: widget.progress,
        color: AppColors.buttonPrimary,
      );
```

How should I update this?